# How to make dynamic POJO class?

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am using Spring and Hibernate for CRUD operation of product table.

[image]

I have got model product.java

[image]

product model is defined as below:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
 import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
 import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;

 @Entity
 @Table(name = "PRODUCT")
 public class Product {
private long gtin;
private String brandname;
private String subbrandname;
private String functionalname;

@Id 
@Column(name = "gtin",unique=true)
public long getGtin() {
    return gtin;
}

public void setGtin(long gtin) {
    this.gtin = gtin;
}

@Column(name = "brand_name")
public String getBrandName() {
    return brandname;
}

@Column(name = "brand_name")
public void setBrandName(String brandname) {
    this.brandname = brandname;
}
```

The question is that field and data type of table product could be changed as per user input. Therefore how can I make product model dynamic so that I don't need to change code of product model in future. The changes can be made based on user input from the forms.

Here, I am using programmatic configuration of hibernate sessionfactory.

Comment: so is your database table going to be dynamic as well?

Comment: yes, as per requirement database table get changes when administrator save changes in the forms. That can be adding new fields or changing data type or changing field name of table.

Comment: Why would you even want to change dynamically? Why dont you store your fields in a consistent datatype format?

Comment: there could be condition where additional attributes can be added in product table or may not be needed in future so I want to make model dynamic to avoid changing code in many places in future.